# postgresql ERROR: syntax error at or near "RETURNS"

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, database-trigger

I'm completely new to psql. And when I use 
http://sqlfiddle.com/ 
to do some homework, the system return this error.

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "RETURNS"
```

Any help is appreciated.
Here is my psql:

```
CREATE TABLE HotelStays
(roomNum INTEGER NOT NULL,
arrDate DATE NOT NULL,
depDate DATE NOT NULL,
guestName CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (roomNum, arrDate))
;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION stopInsert RETURNS trigger AS
$body$
DECLARE
  availableArrDate DATE;
  checkRoomNum INTEGER;
BEGIN
  if (NEW.arrDate >= NEW.depDate) then
    return null;
   end if;

  checkRoomNum = NEW.roomNum;

  select h.depDate into availableArrDate
  from HotelStays h
  where h.roomNum = checkRoomNum
  order by h.depDate DESC
  LIMIT 1;
  if (availableArrDate > NEW.arrDate)
    return null;
  end if;
END;
$body$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

create trigger stopInsert before insert ON HotelStays 
For each row
execute procedure stopInsert();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function name needs to have `()` in it:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION stopInsert() RETURNS trigger AS
                                      ^
--------------------------------------|
```

The `IF` statement is incorrect as well, you are missing the `THEN`

```
if (availableArrDate > NEW.arrDate) then --<< THEN is required
  return null;
end if;
```

---

In SQLFiddle you also need to use a different statement terminator to be able to use the embedded `;` in the PL/pgSQL code:

[image]

You then *keep* the `;` inside the function, but replace all "final" `;` with the `/` on a single line. This is only required for SQLFiddle, not when you use e.g. the command line client `psql` or other Postgres compatible SQL clients.